# How do I get specific values from children in firebase using Swift 4?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, key, children

My Firebase Database

[image]

More specifically, I have randomly generated children(Listings) and from those randomly generated Listings I would like to get the string value from the keys.

For example, if I wanted the Photo URL address, I would like to get the string value of the key "PhotoURL:".

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to get child values from Listings.

```
var ListArr = [ListModel]()


let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Listings")
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] else {
                return
            }

            let Obj = ListModel()
            Obj.UID = snapshot.key
            Obj.PhotoURL = dictionary["PhotoURL"] as? String

            self.ListArr.append(Obj)

        }, withCancel: nil)
```

}

You can set up the model class

```
class ListModel: NSObject {
    var UID:String?
    var PhotoURL:String? 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Yogesh! Im getting an error because I do not currently have a List Model class.  Is there a certain way I should be setting that up, or should I just create the class and initialize PhotoURL, Name, Address ... etc ?

Comment: I have modified the code above to set up the class. You can add you values to the class and then append to the ListArr as shown above.

Comment: Yep, thats what I had. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

First you need to do is to `import Firebase` and then call a function from the Database class like so:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Listings")
```

You can call child recursively to go deeper into your tree

```
//.child("Listings").child("SomeListing").child("PhotoURL")
```

Then call observeSingleEvent to receive the values from firebase.
Your value is stored in the snapshot variable

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in    
            guard let listingsDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            listngsDictionary.forEach({ (key, value) in
                       // Here you can iterate through it
            })
        }) { (err) in
            print("Failed to fetch following listings:", err)
        }
```